# How to update a hyperlink?

Tags: php, updates

I decided to make my database with an active hyperlink so when I find a record I click on an email address and and email is opened. BUT I have a problem with update, When I want to make a correction to the entry and when I press update the email disappears and I get:
Notice: Undefined index: Mail in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/robocze/mydata_dodaj_test_1.php on line 36

I can add records but I can't update...

Can You please help me, thank You

the code:

```
<?php 
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION["sess_user"])){
header("location:login.php");
} else {
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Baza Klientów</title>
</head>
<body>
<h3>Welcome, <?=$_SESSION['sess_user'];?>! <a href="logout.php">Logout</a>   </h3>

<input type="button" onclick="location.href='mydata_dodaj_test_1.php';"  value="Powrót do wyszukiwania" />
<input type="button" onclick="location.href='index.php';" value="MENU powrót" />

<h2><b><center>Wyszukiwanie Klientów ITalents</center></b></h2>

<?php
}
?>    

<?php

$con = mysql_connect("","","","");
if (!$con){
die("Błąd połączenia: " . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("baza",$con); 


if(isset($_POST['update'])) {
$UpdateQuery = "UPDATE Klienci SET id='$_POST[id]', Firma='$_POST[Firma]',   Mail='$_POST[Mail]', Data='$_POST[Data]', Konsultant='$_POST[Konsultant]' WHERE   id='$_POST[hidden]'";
mysql_query($UpdateQuery,$con);
};

if(isset($_POST['add'])) {
$AddQuery = "INSERT INTO Klienci (id, Firma, Mail, Data, Konsultant) VALUES ('$_POST[uid]','$_POST[uFirma]','$_POST[uMail]','$_POST[uData]','$_POST[uKonsultant]')"; // this is the 36 line
mysql_query($AddQuery,$con);
};    

if(isset($_POST['search']))
{
$valueToSearch = $_POST['valueToSearch'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM Klienci WHERE CONCAT(Firma, Mail, Konsultant) LIKE  '%".$valueToSearch."%'";
$search_result = filterTable($query);

}
else {
$query = "SELECT * FROM Klienci ORDER BY id ASC";  
$search_result = filterTable($query);
}

function filterTable($query)   
{
$con = mysql_connect("","","","");
if (!$con){
die("Błąd połączenia: " . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("baza",$con);

$filter_Result = mysql_query($query, $con);
return $filter_Result;
};


echo "<form action=mydata_dodaj_test_1.php method=post>";
echo "<input type=text name=valueToSearch placeholder=wpisz>";
echo "<input type=submit name=search value=Szukaj>";

echo "<table align=center style=text-align:center border=5>
<tr>
<th>ID</th>
<th>Firma</th>
<th>Mail</th>
<th>Data</th>
<th>Konsultant</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($search_result)) {
echo "<form action=mydata_dodaj_test_1.php method=post>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . "<input type=int name=id value=" . $row['id'] . " </td>";
echo "<td>" . "<input type=varchar name=Firma value=" . $row['Firma'] . "   </td>";

echo "<td>" . "<a href='mailto:{$row['Mail']}'>" . $row['Mail'] . " </td>";

echo "<td>" . "<input type=date name=Data value=" . $row['Data'] . " </td>";
echo "<td>" . "<input type=varchar name=Konsultant value=" . $row['Konsultant'] . " </td>";
echo "<td>" . "<input type=hidden name=hidden value=" . $row['id'] . " </td>";
echo "<td>" . "<input type=submit name=update value=update" . " </td>";
echo "</form>";    
}
echo "<form action=mydata_dodaj_test_1.php method=post>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td><input type=text name=uid></td>";
echo "<td><input type=varchar name=uFirma></td>";
echo "<td><input type=text name=uMail></td>";
echo "<td><input type=text name=uData></td>";
echo "<td><input type=text name=uKonsultant></td>";
echo "<td>" . "<input type=submit name=add value=dodaj" . " </td>";
echo "</form>";
echo "</table>";
?>

<input type="button" onclick="location.href='mydata_dodaj_test_1.php';"    value="Powrót do wyszukiwania" />
<input type="button" onclick="location.href='index.php';" value="MENU   powrót" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You've got a lot of forms. It looks like you don't actually have the input[name=Mail] in your update form. You should probably add a hidden input with that value.

Answer (score -1):

As error stated `undefined index` in your update statement

```
$UpdateQuery = "UPDATE Klienci SET id='$_POST[id]', Firma='$_POST[Firma]',   Mail='$_POST[Mail]', Data='$_POST[Data]', Konsultant='$_POST[Konsultant]' WHERE   id='$_POST[hidden]'";
```

you are accessing `$_POST[Mail]` which is no where in your form.

Comment: Don't ever just insert variables like that into an `SQL` query without making them safe or using `prepared` statements.

Comment: Tell OP not me.. i am just telling OP about the undefined index

Comment: in fact the line of the DB which works fine BUT there is no hyperlink looks like this - echo "<td>" . "<input type=varchar name=Mail value=" . $row['Mail'] . " </td>"; and then my version of $UpdateQuery.... is ok But there is no hyperlink... I don't know how to make that a hyperlink can be edited and updated. Above in my my message the hyperlink is shown but I can't update it....